# Expected Value of Exponential Function of a Single Variable

Tags: exponential-function, expected-value

Given that I know:

1) $E(n)=2$ (or expected value of $n$ is $2$)

2) $n$ must be a positive integer ($n=1,2,3,\ldots$)

I am just wondering is there any method to evaluate $E(2^{n-1})$ (the expected value of $2^{n-1}$)

Frankly, I have no clue how this can be solved. But I think it involves some kind of distribution function (since exponential variable is involved here)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Expand $2^{n-1}$ into its Taylor series.

Comment: @TenaliRaman how can this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E(2^{n-1}) = \frac{1}{2} E(2^n) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 2^k P(k)$.

If $P(2) = 1$, then $E(n) =2, E(2^{n-1}) = 2$.

If $P(1) = 1/4, P(2) = 1/2, P(3) = 1/4$, then $E(n) = 2, E(2^{n-1}) = 5/4$, so it depends on the distribution function.